# Preguntas Etiquetas Usuarios Sin responder ¿COMO PUEDO INSERTAR DATOS EN TABLAS FORANEAS? SOLO ME REGISTRA UNA

Tags: php, html

//para empezar tengo 3 tablas
//tabla **usuario**, **area** y **distrito** en las cuales la tabla **usuario** jala las `pk` de **area** y **distrito** en su tabla, y en mi codigo he llegado a insertar en un formulario todo, y en la tabla **usuario** me sale todo normal osea las `fk` normales pero solo en una que es **area** pero la otra `fk` de **distrito** no me sale, antes que nada las dos `fk` son autoincrement, he estado investigando y para que me jale una usea el                 ".$mysqli->insert_id."

---

```
<?php
    require_once("../Trabajo/conexion.php");

    if(
        isset($_POST["DNI"]) &&
        isset($_POST["NOMBREUSU"]) &&
        isset($_POST["APEUSU"]) &&
        isset($_POST["APEMATUSU"]) &&
        isset($_POST["DIREUSU"]) &&
        isset($_POST["NOMDIST"]) &&
        isset($_POST["DESUSU"])
    ){
        $mysqli-> query("INSERT INTO
                distrito(
                    ID_DISTRI,
                    NOM_DISTRI
                )
                VALUES(
                    null,
                    '".$_POST["NOMDIST"]."'
                )
                ");
      
          $mysqli-> query("INSERT INTO
          area(
              ID_AREA,
              DES_AREA
          )
          VALUES(
              null,
              '".$_POST["DESUSU"]."'
          )
          ");
    $mysqli-> query("INSERT INTO 
             usuario
    VALUES(
                '".$_POST["DNI"]."',
                '".$_POST["NOMBREUSU"]."',
                '".$_POST["APEUSU"]."',
                '".$_POST["APEMATUSU"]."',
                null,
                '".$_POST["DIREUSU"]."',
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                ".$mysqli->insert_id."
           
               

                 )
                 ");
               
    };

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El [`insert_id`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php) solo te devuelve el último autoincremento insertado, no todos los realizados; por tanto necesitas crear (te sugiero) 2 variables; una para cada `id` que se genera; aquí las nombrare `$idDistrito` e `$idArea`; tal que, hagas lo siguiente:

```
$mysqli->query("TU INSERT A DISTRITO");
$idDistrito=$mysqli->insert_id;
$mysqli->query("TU INSERT A AREA");
$idArea=$mysqli->insert_id;
```

ya con estas 2 nuevas variables las colocas en la parte de tu `INSERT` a `usuario` donde le corresponda a c/u.

Comment: GRACIAS !!! ME SALIO CON GUARDARLO EN VARIABLES DISTINTAS